# Where do you store a persistent memory value (non db) over the lifetime of an app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say I want to set a variable when my Spring app is instantiated:

```
String timeUp = new Date().toString();
```

I want to be able to access this value from all of my app's beans but I don't want to store it in a database. I just want to save it in a bean in the app that will be accessible from all other beans in the app. How is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Spring Beans are, by default, Singletons.  So just create a bean for this purpose.

```
@Component
public class TimeUp {
  private final String _timeUp = new Date().toString();
  public String getTimeUp() { _timeUp };
}
```

Then inject this bean where you need it.

```
@Component
public class Whatever {
  @Autowired TimeUp timeUp;

  public void useTimeUp() {
     System.out.println(timeUp.getTimeUp());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If everything lives on the same machine, you may want to use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). It's a single instance which everything can easily access and call.

For long term storage, if a database isn't an option, you may want to [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Java) your bean to a file, or simply write your own file format and output to that.

Answer (score 1):

A singleton initialized in a `ContextListener`'s `contextInitialized` method would be my first point of call.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use of a singleton. If you have only a few of these, you can create a singleton per value. If you have a bunch of these, you can write a 'service' where you set and lookup values.

In spring, you can do this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;

public class TimeUp implements FactoryBean<String> {
  private final String _value = new Date().toString();

  public String getObject() {
    return _value;

  public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return String.class;
  }

  public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then in Spring, you would simply do:

```
<bean id="timeUp" class="example.TimeUp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing this would be to let one of your servlet classes or filter classes have a public static final member of  type Date and on the declaration line set it to a new date object. then you can do "servlet class name (dot) public member name" to access this value.

if you do it in a servlet, you must declare that servlet inside your web.xml as a "load-on-startup" servlet. otherwise it won't get its date value until the first time that servlet is used, and that's not really what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually just want the apps uptime, you should be able to use the following

```
RuntimeMXBean mx = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
long uptimeInMillis = mx.getUptime();
```

If you are looking for a more abstract answer, then Chris gave a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Singleton:

```
public class Environment {

    private final long startTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime();

    public long getStartTime() {
        return this.startTime;
    }


    private static final Environment SINGLETON = new Environment();

    private Environment() {
        //nop
    }

    public static Environment getInstance() {
        return SINGLETON;
    }
}
```